# Broken scroll in Firefox with flex items

Tags: html, css, scroll, flexbox

I have a snippet of my problem in this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/fsdjvv40/

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.main, .main-panel {
    flex: 1;
}

.content-wrapper, .main {
    display: flex;
}

.content-wrapper {
    flex: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}

.sidebar-menu {
    background: #2f2f2f;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.infinite-scroll-component {
    flex: 1 1 0px;
    display: flex;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    will-change: contents;
    transform: translateZ(0);
    background: yellow;
}

.main-panel {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px 30px 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="sidebar-menu"></div>
    <div class="infinite-scroll-component">
      <div class="main-panel">
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
        <h1>PEPE</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the basic problem is that in Firefox the scroll of the given snippet it's not working.But in other browsers, it is working (Chrome, safari).

Can anybody explain me why is this behavior happening? will interesting to know the reason :)

Comment: Add `min-height: 0` to `.main`. https://jsfiddle.net/fsdjvv40/1/